# EF Core 2.1 'UNIQUE constraint failed: People.ReferredById'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

My Data Model

```
Table("People")]
public abstract class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReferredBy")]
    public long? ReferredById { get; set; }
    public User ReferredBy { get; set; }
}


public class User : Person
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string RollNo { get; set; }

}
```

Fluent API to set null on delete

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(t => t.ReferredBy)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

Now when i try to insert a row with same ReferredByit throws an unique constraint error. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please show your code where the error is occurring.

Comment: check the object which you are inserting into DB. Does it have ReferredBy  object? If yes it means you are inserting row in User  table also.

Comment: What is the relationship for `Person`? I fail to add-migration based on your current design. What is your expected table?

Comment: @viveknuna No i tried using postman like below {
 "Name":"s1",
  "ReferredById":1

}

Comment: @Edward Only a single table for person and will have descriptor for user

Comment: @Brad      public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Student student)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _Context.Add(student);
            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }

Comment: Why `.WithOne()`? That makes the relationship one-to-one, hence the unique constraint error. It should be `.WithMany()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev But a person can be updated by one user only right? then its one to one mapping.

Comment: Indeed, for person it's one, hence `HasOne`. But for referrer it's many, hence `WithMany`. In other words, one person can have one referrer. one user can be referrer to many (multiple) people.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much @IvanStoev

Comment: I am wondering how you create your database. Is your database SQL Server?

Comment: No Sqlite. Why wondering?